# Does NUnit affect performance?

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper

It seems that when I launch NUnit test with Resharper unit tests launcher, performance is affected.

Is it true or I observe some incidental execution time deviations? Any explanations?

Comment: What version of ReSharper are you using? IIRC, the initial 5.1 release had some performance problems running NUnit tests (especially when you have a large test assembly), but this is fixed in 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly I have always found running NUnit tests with Resharper slow. While I use Resharper in the IDE, I use TestDriven.net (http://www.testdriven.net/) to run my NUnit test. It's much faster.